# Configure CORS in IBM Cloud Object Storage Bucket using CLI

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage, cloud-object-storage

I am trying to configure CORS in my IBM Cloud Object Storage bucket. I dont see any option to do that from bucket configuration in UI and I can see it can only be done through CLI. The command looks similar to how its done in AWS CLI as well. This is the command to configure CORS,

```
ibmcloud cos bucket-cors-put --bucket BUCKET_NAME [--cors-configuration STRUCTURE] [--region REGION] [--output FORMAT]
```

It is expecting cors configuration STRUCTURE in JSON format from a file and add it as `--cors-configuration file://<filename.json>`. I have created a configuration file as cors.json and saved it on my Desktop. But when I am providing path for that file and running the command, I am getting this error,
**The value in flag '--cors-configuration' is invalid**

I am providing file path like this - `--cors-configuration file:///C:/Users/KirtiJha/Desktop/cors.json`

I am new with Cloud CLI. Am I doing wrong here? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is the `file` scheme necessary? Have you tried dropping `file://` and simply specifying a file path?

Comment: Yes. I tried that but unfortunately did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure CORS in the CLI or [via API and SDKs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cos/cos-compatibility#putbucketcors). On the CLI, you can use the IBM Cloud COS plugin in the [bucket-cors-put command](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-cli-plugin-ic-cos-cli#ic-set-bucket-cors) as you mentioned.

The file URI seems valid to me. You could try to set it in quotes ("file:///..."). Also, try to copy the file into your current directory and then test with `--cors-configuration file://cors.json`.